# Как правильно оформляется перечисление вопросов?

Tags: синтаксис, стилистика

Например, есть следующее предложение.

Родители должны собраться и обсудить: Что дети будут читать? Где они будут гулять? С кем и как они будут общаться?

Как правильно расставить знаки препинания? Кавычки? Может быть, нужно переформулировать так, чтобы избавиться от двоеточия?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Возможны разные варианты:**

1. БСП: Родители должны собраться и обсудить: что дети будут читать? где они будут гулять? с кем и как они будут общаться?
2. СПП: Родители должны собраться и обсудить, что дети будут читать, где они будут гулять, кем и как они будут общаться? (Вопрос ставится при ярко выраженной вопросительной интонации).
3. Родители должны собраться и обсудить конкретные вопросы. Что дети будут читать? Где они будут гулять? С кем и как они будут общаться?

[Розенталь](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/41.htm) §76. Вопросительный знак

Comment: *Вопрос ставится при ярко выраженной вопросительной интонации.* Правда? А где можно найти источник с подтверждением этому?

Comment: У Розенталя в приведенной ссылке: Постановка вопросительного знака после предложения с косвенным вопросом встречается, если последний содержит сильно выраженную вопросительную интонацию, например: Не понимаю, что тебе нужно? (Чехов); Я спросил, как же он стал отшельником? (Горький).

Comment: А-а, точно, простите! Не прочитал этого мелкого шрифта.

Comment: О! Розенталь, параграф про вопросительный знак! Спасибо! Я не догадался сразу, где искать.

Answer (score 4):

Я бы не избавлялась от двоеточия - оно на месте. После двоеточия - всё со строчной, каждое внутреннее вопросительное предложение внутри общего повествовательного. Это же темы того, что родители собрались обсудить, то есть у нас есть обобщающее слово.

***Родители должны собраться и обсудить: что дети будут читать? где они будут гулять? с кем и как они будут общаться?***

В теме "[Знаки конца предложения внутри предложения](http://www.telenir.net/jazykoznanie/pravila_russkoi_orfografii_i_punktuacii_polnyi_akademicheskii_spravochnik/p3.php)" нам подходит § 5, который цитирую (можно посмотреть и соседние параграфы).

> При смысловом подчеркивании отдельных членов вопросительного или
>   восклицательного предложения знаки препинания ставятся после каждого
>   из членов, которые оформляются как самостоятельная синтаксическая
>   единица, т. е. начинаются с прописной буквы: — Что вас привело к ним?
>   — неожиданно бытовым, ворчливым голосом спросил он. — Недомыслие?
>   Страх? Голод? (А. Т.); — Где же те силы, которые питают национальный
>   дух и делают русского русским, узбека узбеком, а немца немцем?
>   Природа? Среда обитания? Вообще среда? Язык? Предания? История?
>   Религия? Литература и вообще искусство? И что тут стоит на первом
>   месте? (Сол.); — Аннушка, наша Аннушка! С Садовой! Это ее работа!
>   (Булг.).
>
> ***Однако прописные буквы заменяются строчными, если перед перечислением
>   стоят знаки двоеточие или тире (впереди имеется обобщение):*** Всё
>   отвергал: законы! совесть! веру! (Тр.); Она спросила, кто он, не
>   француз ли, и стала по его просьбе гадать: бельгиец? датчанин?
>   голландец? (Наб.); Вот так играть свою игру — шутя! всерьез! до слез!
>   навеки! не лукавя! — как он играл, как, молоко лакая, играет с миром
>   зверь или дитя (Ахмад.).
>
> **Примечание.** В других случаях (при отсутствии знаков двоеточия или тире перед перечислением) подобные написания со строчной буквой не
>   соответствуют современной пунктуационной норме, например: Зачем же
>   здесь? и в этот час? (Гр.); Что мне делать? просить прощения? хорошо,
>   да в чем? (П.).

См. также у Валгиной:

[**Вопросительный и восклицательный знаки внутри предложения**](http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik/222-voprositelnyiy-vosklitsatelnyiy-znaki-90763.html)